# Adding 2 dimensional array rows

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
for (row=0; row<8; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col<8; col++)
        {
            answer+=my_data[row][col];
        }
        printf("The sum of row %i is: %i\n", row,answer);
        answer = 0;//to reset answer back to zero for next row sum 
    }
```

I have an 8x8 array and I'm adding each row and resetting the answer back to zero so you get the exact answer for each row. However it's not working... What is wrong?

Comment: Do you set answer to 0 before the loops start?

Comment: How about changing `answer = 0;` to the start of the bucle?

Comment: When you say not working, what exactly is not working? compilation error? strange value coming out? etc. also how are answer,row,col declared?

Comment: Put some example to explain your problem

Comment: No I did not. Thanks for catching my error haha I forgot to initialize it to zero!

Comment: Do you Declared the row and col as before u use it, and i tested the same using C# its working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How is `answer` declared ?

If it is declared without an initial value then your existing code will fail as `answer` will have junk value for 1st row. To fix this :

```
for (row=0; row<8; row++) {
        answer = 0; // clear the running sum.
        for (col=0; col<8; col++) {
            answer+=my_data[row][col];
        }
        printf("The sum of row %i is: %i\n", row,answer);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to initialize answer to zero in the beginning of the program.

```
int answer = 0;
```

Thanks Gunner and Pedro.